# Borel-Cantelli lemma and $\limsup$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a pretty quick question. Let $X_1, X_2, ...$ be i.i.d. non-negative random variables. Assume that
$$P( X_n > n \ \text{i.o.} ) = 0.$$
Does this imply that
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} X_n < \limsup_{n \to \infty} n = \infty$$?

I think this is true from Borel-Cantelli but I just want to make sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be IID $\textrm{Exp}(1)$ random variables. Then
$$\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}P(X_n>n)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}P(X_1>n)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}e^{-n}<\infty$$
This implies $P(X_n>n\textrm{ i.o.})=0$ by B-C I. However, for any $N>0$:
$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}P(X_n\geq N)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\underbrace{P(X_1\geq N)}_{>0}=\infty$$
So $P(X_n\geq N\textrm{ i.o.})=1$ for all $N>0$ by B-C II. But then
$$\begin{aligned}P\bigg(\limsup_{n \to \infty}X_n\geq N\bigg)&=P\bigg(\inf_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\sup_{k\geq n}X_k\geq N\bigg)\geq \\
&\geq P\bigg(\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\bigg\{\sup_{k\geq n}X_k\geq N\bigg\}\bigg)\geq \\
&\geq P\bigg(\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{k\geq n}\{X_k\geq N\}\bigg)=1\end{aligned}$$
So $P(\limsup_{n \to \infty}X_n= \infty)=1$.

---

Suppose $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ are only independent.

Let $X_n(\omega)=n-1$. Then, $X_n$ are nonnegative, $P(X_n>n\textrm{ i.o.})=0$ but $\limsup_{n}X_n(\omega)=\infty$ for all $\omega$.